# Master/detail flow layout and Android annotations

Tags: layout, tablet, android-annotations, handset

I need to make an Android app that adjusts itself to handset and tablets. It's like the master/detail flow layout.

I will use Android Annotation do simplify the development.

How to create an application that adjusts itself for tablets (two panels) and handsets (single panel) using Android annotations?

Answer (score 0):

try this: An Android Master/Detail Flow Tutorial

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial/

Comment: But I found this http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial.